# Python-Why aren't my elif statements not getting evaluated in this recursive multiplication which takes into account negative numbers

Tags: python, function, recursion

Hi I have looked up a few recursive multiplication of 2 numbers in python, but none of them take into account the possibility of negative numbers or if they do they don't explain the entire steps.

I have coded the following the program but I am getting an error, can someone please let me know what is wrong with it?

```
def mult(a,b):
    if a==0 | b==0:
        return 0
    elif a==1:
        return b
    elif a > 0 & b >0:
        return b + mult(a-1,b)
    elif  a < 0 & b > 0:
        return - b + mult(a+1,b))
    elif a > 0 & b < 0:
        return - b + mult(a-1, b))
    else:
        return -b + mult(a+1, b)

print(mult(-4,5))
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Apart from anything else, the relevant operators in Python are `and` and `or`, not `&` and `|`.

Comment: I was getting "maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison" but this was because my elif statements were not getting evaluated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`|` and `&` are bitwise operators, not logical operators, and their [(relatively) high precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) means that `a > 0 & b >0` is parsed as `a > (0 & b) > 0`, which is not what you want.  Use `or` and `and` instead.

Comment: Thanks I was looking for a JS equivalent for and & and the first thing that came up on google search was &, same goes for or (|| in JS).

Answer (score 1):

In your elif statement, you're using a bitwise "and" operator rather than the logical and operator. Everywhere that you have "&" replace it with "and"

Comment: This is Python.  There is no `&&`.

Answer (score 1):

You have some python syntax errors and some sign problems. This works for mult(-4,5) and mult(5,-4).

```
def mult(a,b):
    if a == 0 or b == 0:
         return 0
    elif a == 1:
        return b
    elif b == 1:
        return a
    elif a >0 and b > 0:
        return b + mult(a-1,b)
    elif a < 0 and b > 0:
        return -b+mult(a+1,b)
    elif a > 0 and b < 0:
        return b+mult(a-1,b)
    else:
        return b + mult(a+1,b)
```

Comment: As mentioned above technically using & isn't a "syntax error" and more just using something you shouldn't (bitwise operators versus logical operators)

Comment: Yes I realized that, thanks for pointing out though. for a<0 and b>0 the correct statement should have been -b + mult(a+1,b). Thanks again!

Comment: Also the in the else block it should be else: return -b + mult(a+1,b)