# my python code is not working when I use the & along with the if condition; but when I use a nested if loop it works fine

Tags: python-3.x

```
for i in range(0, 51):
    if(i%2!=0 & i%3!=0):
        print(i)
```

This code does not yield any result;
whereas when I use a nested if loop, it works smoothly

```
for i in range(0,51):
    if(i%2!=0):
        if(i%3!=0):
            print(i)
```

Comment: `&` means AND bitwise operator, it has higher precedence than `!=`. Use `and` if you wanted a logical AND.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python-Why aren't my elif statements not getting evaluated in this recursive multiplication which takes into account negative numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51386324/python-why-arent-my-elif-statements-not-getting-evaluated-in-this-recursive-mul)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taked any comparison operation between brackets:

```
for i in range(0, 51): 
    if(i%2!=0) & (i%3!=0): 
        print(i)
```